# How to make button come down after edit text field?

Tags: android, button

I have a piece of code which shows a static text, an edit text as a search box and a submit button to submit the query .

The code kind of looks like this :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView;
    private EditText edittext;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mine);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText("Enter your search String :");
        addKeyListener();
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    //Implement the method
    public void addKeyListener() {
        // get edit text component
        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
        // add a key listener to keep track user input
        edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // if key down and "enter" is pressed
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                // display a floating message
                Toast.makeText(RecipeActivity.this,
                    edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            } else if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9)) {

                // display a floating message
                Toast.makeText(RecipeActivity.this,
                    "Aboriginal text!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
     });
    }

    //Implement the button
    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

              /* I will capture the search string here */
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The  activity screen comes up like  this :

[image]

**EDIT :** The XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".RecipeActivity" >

      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      </TextView>

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:label="@string/search_label" 
        android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
        <requestFocus />
      </EditText>

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see the submit button is overlapping the edit text search box. How can i make the button element come down ?

Comment: Show us your xml layout file

Comment: I have provided the xml layout.

Comment: android:layout_below="@+id/searchText"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` in your xml Layout because it's much cheaper than `RelativeLayout` to render.

Solution with `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you have to use `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/searchText"
    android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

See [RelativeLayout Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) for further Informations.

Answer (score 0):

Use   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in your

Answer (score 0):

add **android:below** reference

```
    <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:below="@+id/searchText"
                android:text="Submit" />
```